# If a group scheme $G$ operates on another scheme $X$, how do you define orbits?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, toric-geometry

In my specific case, $G=\mathrm{Spec}(k[M])$ is an algebraic torus acting on a toric variety $X_\Sigma$ corresponding to a fan $\Sigma$ when $k$ is not necessarily algebraically closed (or maybe even $k=\mathbb{Z}$). I see how one still can define the distinguished points $x_\sigma$, but how would the $G$-orbit of $x_\sigma$ be defined?

My problem is that my working definition of orbits uses points. Of course, I can consider $T$-valued points for any $T$ and get orbits of those, but how do they fit together?

Comment: Well, the $T$-valued points lying in an orbit forms a subfunctor of $X(-)$, and you can ask whether this subfunctor corresponds to a subscheme.

Comment: But which orbit to take? If $T=\mathrm{Spec}(K)$ for some extension field of $k(x_\sigma)$ then probably the orbit of a $T$-valued point with locality $x_\sigma$. But which of those? And what to do for arbitrary $T$?

Answer (score 4):

If you have a group scheme $G\to S$, acting on an $S$-scheme $X$, then for any $T$-valued point $\rho : T\to X$ of $X$, the orbit of $\rho$ can be defined as the image of the natural map 
$$ G_T=G\times_S T \stackrel{1 \times \rho}{\to} G\times_S X  \stackrel{\mu}{\to} X$$
where $\mu$ defines the action of $G$ on $X$. The orbit usualy is not closed (constructible under mild conditions), but one can consider the Zariski closure of the orbit, this is called orbit closure in Fulton's book on toric varieties.

Comment: That really makes sense, thanks. What is a good reference for this and related questions?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find a reference. In the case of toric varieties, $x_\sigma$ is defined over the smallest possible field (or even $\mathbb Z$). The orbit over $k$ is the projection to $X_\Sigma$ of the orbit over an algebraic closure.